# Need help deserializing JSON Object returned from API

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have the following JSON Output:

```
{{
  "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.PagedResult`1[[Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericEntityData, Asi.Contracts]], Asi.Contracts",
  "Items": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericEntityData, Asi.Contracts]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericEntityData, Asi.Contracts",
        "EntityTypeName": "14",
        "Properties": {
          "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyDataCollection, Asi.Contracts",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "ResultRow",
              "Value": "1"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Work Phone",
              "Value": "(782) 438-7600"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Email",
              "Value": "agsaz@rmax.net"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Full Name",
              "Value": "Agazny"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "iMISId",
              "Value": "eg1"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Preferred Phone",
              "Value": "780"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Organization",
              "Value": "Re"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericEntityData, Asi.Contracts",
        "EntityTypeName": "14",
        "Properties": {
          "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyDataCollection, Asi.Contracts",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "ResultRow",
              "Value": "2"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Work Phone",
              "Value": "7802"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Email",
              "Value": "aksm"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Full Name",
              "Value": "Aji"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "iMISId",
              "Value": "esa"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Preferred Phone",
              "Value": "780"
            },
            {
              "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
              "Name": "Organization",
              "Value": "Hom"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

I am trying to deserialize this response into workable c# objects and POST it to a different API that accepts a totally different format of JSON.

This is my code so far:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
      // Format headers
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

      // Request token, and append to headers
      await AddTokenToHeaders(client);

      // Query HTTP Service                
      var response = await client.GetAsync(baseUrl + "api/IQA?querydocumentversionkey=f2005a6e-7f47-47c3-a7e7-bbd2a7b6ab38");

      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
           var customer = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           JObject result = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

           JArray a = (JArray)result["Items"]["$values"][0]["Properties"];
           var test =  a.AsJEnumerable();
```

However, it's not picking up my entire JSON object and I am not able to map it to the properties of my class:

--Update.

I have updated my code and I was able to get the Jarray in the format I wanted, however when I try enumerate by jObject into my List of Class Customer, the properties I try to cast returns nulls.

Thanks for the response. I was able to get the output I was looking for by using the following code. However, attempting to put the output in my List of Customer class with the properties specified however, I am getting nulls on the properties of class Customer.

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                JArray a = (JArray)result["Items"]["$values"];
                List<Customer> items = ((JArray)a).Select(x => new Customer
                {
                    ResultRow = (string)x["ResultRow"],
                    WorkPhone = (string)x["Work Phone"],
                    Email = (string)x["Email"],
                    FullName = (string)x["Full Name"],
                    iMISId = (string)x["iMISId"],
                    PreferredPhone = (string)x["Preferred Phone"],
                    Organization = (string)x["Organization"]
                }).ToList();


 public class Customer
    {
        [JsonProperty("ResultRow")]
        public string ResultRow { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Work Phone")]
        public string WorkPhone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("iMISId")]
        public string iMISId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Preferred Phone")]
        public string PreferredPhone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Organization")]
        public string Organization { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not picking up my entire JSON object"?

Comment: BTW, do not dispose HttpClient.

Comment: Parsing is not the same as deserializing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the code you provided. You are trying to cast the `Properties` into a `JArray` when it is an object.

If you do want the array in the `Properties` object, do this:

```
JArray arr = (JArray)result["Items"]["$values"][0]["Properties"]["$values"];
```

Otherwise, if you are looking for the `Properties` object, then you should do this instead:

```
JObject obj = (JObject)result["Items"]["$values"][0]["Properties"];
```

Finally, to rebuild the list of `Customer` instances, you could use the following logic with the static methods:

```
var customersJson = (JArray)result["Items"]["$values"];

var customers = new List<Customer>();

foreach (JObject o in customersJson)
{
     var customerJson = (JArray) o["Properties"]["$values"];
     customers.Add(BuildCustomer(customerJson));
}
```

[...]

```
private static Customer BuildCustomer(JArray a)
{
    return new Customer
    {
        ResultRow = GetValue(a, "ResultRow"),
        WorkPhone = GetValue(a, "Work Phone"),
        Email = GetValue(a, "Email"),
        FullName = GetValue(a, "Full Name"),
        iMISId = GetValue(a, "iMISId"),
        PreferredPhone = GetValue(a, "Preferred Phone"),
        Organization = GetValue(a, "Organization")
     };
}

private static string GetValue(JArray array, string name)
{
    JToken obj = array.FirstOrDefault(x => (string) x["Name"] == name);

    if (obj == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return (string) obj["Value"];
}
```

Comment: I've edited my original comment and added the changes I've made to my code and where I'm stuck now

Comment: @Junior I have edited my answer to include the deserialization of a Customer out of a JArray. If it does answer your question, please mark it as an answer so that it can help someone else.

Comment: Thanks this works, but it only builds a single customer. I want to deseriliaze the entire response using:

  JArray a = (JArray)result["Items"]["$values"] 

This will return many Customer records. I want to store this in a c# collection. I thought the JArray function does that, but it does not.

Comment: thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. Syntax for the foreach loop is perfect! Thanks again